# 301 redirect based on request domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

so i'm looking to 301 redirect my old domain to my new one, although I would only like to do the redirect for a specific request domain.

currently I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.net[NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

although it's not working. The redirect only needs to be done when it matches the domain the request is coming from with olddomain.net

Does anyone see anything wrong with that?

Thanks

Comment: Need whitespace before `[NC]`. Otherwise, it looks correct.

Comment: @BelginFish: Can you tell in detail me what's not working?

Comment: After adding the space it's almost working. All the subpages are being redirected but not the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the first line and just keep the second line nd it would still work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.net[NC] #remove this line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Removing that line will redirect everything (www and non-www links).

but the problem you are having is there is no space after `.net` and [NC]

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.net [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```